# How to find 10 most frequent words in the file in Unix/Linux

Tags: linux, unix

How to find 10 most frequent words in the file in Unix/Linux?

I tried using this command in Unix:

```
sort file.txt | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -10
```

However I am not sure if it's correct and whether it is showing me 10 most frequent words in the large file.

Comment: Is `file.txt` just one word per line? Or are there multiple words per line?

Comment: yes it has one word per line

Comment: `awk '{cnt[$1]++} END{for (e in cnt) printf "%s\t%s\n", cnt[e], e}' file.txt | sort -nr | head -n 10`

Comment: 23751  - 1, 
7541  -  2, 
3806  -  3, 
2335  -  4, 
1616  -  5, 
1149  -  6,
899  -   7, 
709  -   8, 
601   -  9, 
471  -   10,  its showing me 10 words with number of frequency but I also need to see the words

Comment: Please add example input and desired output.

Comment: Why do you think your result is wrong?

Comment: in  your condition , one line  with more than one word  has some problems   ,it willn't  be splited. such as 
  `3 we we`

Answer (score 1):

I have a shell  demo  to deal with your  problem  ,even  you have  a file  with  more than one  Word in one line

wordcount.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# filename: wordcount.sh
# usage: word count

# handle position arguments
if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
    echo "Usage: $0 filename"
    exit -1
fi

# realize word count
printf "%-14s%s\n" "Word" "Count"

cat $1 | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' | \
egrep -o "\b[[:alpha:]]+\b" | \
awk '{ count[$0]++ }
END{
for(ind in count)
{ printf("%-14s%d\n",ind,count[ind]); }
}' | sort -k2 -n -r | head -n 10
```

just  run  `./wordcount.sh  filename.txt`

explain
Use the tr command to convert all uppercase letters to lowercase letters, then use the egrep command to grab all the words in the text and output them item by item. Finally, use the awk command and the associative array to implement the word count function, and decrement the output according to the number of occurrences. .